# How to use -tagFile option with CSVExcelStorage in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have to get the filename with each row so i used

```
data = LOAD 'data.csv' using PigStorage(',','-tagFile') AS (filename:chararray);
```

But in data.csv some columns have comma(,) in content as well so to handle comma issue i used

```
data = LOAD 'data.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage()AS (filename:chararray);
```

But I didn't get any option to use -tagFile option with CSVExcelStorage.
Please let me know how can i use CSVExcelStorage and -tagFile option at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the way to perform both operation(get the file name in each row and replace delimiter if it appears in column content)

```
data = LOAD 'data.csv' using PigStorage(',','-tagFile') AS (filename:chararray, record:chararray);

/*replace comma(,) if it appears in column content*/
replaceComma = FOREACH data GENERATE filename, REPLACE (record, ',(?!(([^\\"]*\\"){2})*[^\\"]*$)', '');

/*replace the quotes("") which is present around the column if it have comma(,) as its a csv file feature*/
replaceQuotes = FOREACH replaceComma GENERATE filename, REPLACE ($4,'"','') as record;
```

Once data is loaded properly without comma , i am free to perform any operation.
Detailed use case is available at [my blog](http://www.bigjavaspace.com/app/article/read/Pig_Tips_and_Tricks_Part1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use -tagefile with [CSVExcelStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html) since CSVExcelStorage does not have -tagFile option.The workaround is to change the delimiter of the file and use PigStorage with the new delimiter and -tagFile or replace the comma in your data.

Comment: I am not able to change delimiter of file using regex and replace As its also replacing comma(,) inside quotes as well. I need a regex which replace comma(,) inside quotes only using Pig. I dont have option to use unix/linux commands.